# How many ways you can form a committee of 4? (Combinations with Restrictions)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In How many ways you can form a committee of 4 from 2 Math Teachers and 5 English Teachers. Such that a committee should not include both math teachers (i.e a committee can have one math teacher or None).

This can be solved with but how can we justify this process or answer with intuition/explanation ?:
$$ \binom{7}{4} - \binom{5}{2} =25$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no restrictions, then there are obviously $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ members from the total $2 + 5 = 7$ teachers.

Among those unrestricted choices, how many of them include both math teachers?  Well, there is just one way to choose both math teachers:  $\binom{2}{2}$.  And there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ of the $5$ English teachers.  So in total, the number of disallowed choices is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{2} = \binom{5}{2}$.